# Defining a function in python turtles that will change the background color depending on inputs of day, evening, night

Tags: python

I am a beginner and need help with Python Turtles. My school assignment is to make a function that will change a picture we make with Turtles to either day, evening, or night. I have tried the following, but can't understand why it isn't working. It also says that the specific time of day is not defined. Any help would be great.

```
def draw_scene(time):

    screen = turtle.Screen()
    
    if time == day:
        screen.bgcolor("white")
    elif time == evening:
        screen.bgcolor("purple")
    elif time == night:
        screen.bgcolor("black")
        return`
```

Comment: What is `time`, `day`, `evening` and `night`? What errors are you getting? Please, show a [mcve] and include all important information.

Comment: The errors I am getting are that day, evening, and night are not defined. I thought that I was defining them correctly? They purpose is to be able to put draw_scene(day) and have the background be white and so on with evening and night.

Comment: They aren't defined anywhere in the code here. What value do you expect `day` to have for example?

Comment: I guess that's what I'm confused about. So I thinking about it, I would want day = "white". I did that before, but it still said 'day is not defined'. Something is happening that I'm not grasping I guess. Sorry I'm just really new to this.

Comment: If you did `day = "white"` somewhere else, that does indeed assign `"white"` to `day`. If it's saying `day` isn't defined though, you defined `day` in a local scope somewhere. That's why I requested a [mcve]. There isn't enough detail to help you, other than by telling you to define the variables it's saying aren't defined. You may need to read up on **variable scope** to understand where you can reference variables from.

Comment: Okay I will try doing that and then trying some stuff out. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply add `''`around day, evening and night to make the code work.

```
def draw_scene(time):

screen = turtle.Screen()

if time == 'day':
    screen.bgcolor("white")
elif time == 'evening':
    screen.bgcolor("purple")
elif time == 'night':
    screen.bgcolor("black")
    return`
```

Comment: Thank you! This helped! I appreciate it!